# name 'df' is not defined in box plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot box plot with some data, but I am getting `name 'df' is not defined` error. Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
% matplotlib inline

# load the dataset 
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Kumar Chandan/Downloads/indiavix.csv") 

# display 5 rows of dataset 
df.head()

df=df.boxplot(column =['close'], grid = False)
```

Comment: Are you using jupyter?

Comment: Could you format your question?  please

Comment: What line are you getting the error at? `df = pd.read_csv(...)`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
df.boxplot(column =['close'], grid = False)
```

By putting `df =` at the front of that line you are assigning the output of the line (the plot) back to df which erases your dataframe.

Comment: If this answers your question, please select it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assign value again to data frame.
In place of assigning use

```
df.boxplot(column =['close'], grid = False)
```